# Is there an android shape visual editor?

Tags: android, svg, shapes, eps

Is there an android shape visual editor? Or is there a way to convert .svg or .eps to Android shape xml? I don't want to include an svg library such as this one if I can just convert it.
http://code.google.com/p/svg-android/

Answer (score 2):

> Is there an android shape visual editor?

Not that I am aware of.

> Or is there a way to convert .svg or .eps to Android shape xml?

The Android `ShapeDrawable` is a very limited format, suitable for a single rectangle or circle (with stroke and fill), but that is it. Converting from EPS or SVG to `ShapeDrawable` would be fruitless, IMHO.

> I don't want to include an svg library such as this one if I can just convert it.

Even that library cannot handle very complex SVG, as I understand it.